# Помогите с запятыми 4

Tags: пунктуация

Вызывают сомнения два вводных слова, между которыми стоит союз. Ставится перед союзом запятая или нет?

К сожалению(,) или к счастью, нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Возможны оба варианта**, мне больше нравится вариант (1) с паузой и запятой.

(1) К сожалению, **или к счастью**, нет. Присоединительный союз ИЛИ, сравнить: К сожалению, **а может быть к счастью**, нет.

(2) **К сожалению или к счастью**, нет. Разделительный союз ИЛИ, нет запятой. Можно изменить предложение: **К сожалению или, может быть,  к счастью**, нет.

Пример с присоединительным союзом ИЛИ:  Я прочитал, или почти прочитал, всю книгу.

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибиться, но мне кажется, что "к сожалению или к счастью" здесь становится единой вводной конструкцией. В таком случае первая запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны, потому что, как правильно заметил Артём Луговой, *к сожалению или к счастью* здесь - цельное вводное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Я не слышала про "цельное" вводное выражение. Но смею предположить, что это просто однородные вводные конструкции. Как при любых других однородных членах с неповторяющимся союзом ИЛИ, запятая здесь не нужна.

*К сожалению или к счастью, нет.*